# golang: How to define a sequence of steps

Tags: list, go, slice, sequence, composite-literals

I want to write a protocol test. My current idea is to define a series of steps. Each Step contains a `Trigger` and `Expectation` - e.g. trigger `MsgA` and expect `MsgB`.

```
type Series struct {
  Steps []Step
}
```

What I don't like about this, is that the `Series` is not explicit: I would have to either create the slice in sequence and then hope it never gets messed up, and rely on it, or `sort` it and then have to implement the sort funcs, which is utterly unnecessary.

What is a good design to formally define the `Series`, and in this way make it explicit?

The best idea I have for now is to create a map with `int` indexes:

```
type Series struct {
   Steps map[int]Step
}

series := Series{
   Steps: map[int]Step{
     0: Step{},
     1: Step{},
     2: Step{},
     ...
   }
}
```

Another option could be to build myself a linked list. `go` doesn't have an implementation (afaik). It feels odd to have to build one myself for this. But such a solution would also loose the explicit feature a bit: Basically you always have to navigate through the linked list to get the whole sequence (e.g. "what is step 4").

Comment: You can use keyed composite literal for this purpose: `var steps = []Step{0: Step{}, 1: Step{}, ...}`

Comment: holy @#$@! @icza please provide this as a solution, I didn't even know this was possible!!! And I am several years working in `go` now...shame on me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a map, you can still use a slice and use a *keyed* [composite literal](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Composite_literals):

```
var steps = []Step{
    0: Step{},
    1: Step{},
    ...
}
```

This is detailed in [Spec: Composite literals](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Composite_literals):

> ```
> CompositeLit  = LiteralType LiteralValue .
> LiteralType   = StructType | ArrayType | "[" "..." "]" ElementType |
>                 SliceType | MapType | TypeName [ TypeArgs ] .
> LiteralValue  = "{" [ ElementList [ "," ] ] "}" .
> ElementList   = KeyedElement { "," KeyedElement } .
> KeyedElement  = [ Key ":" ] Element .
> Key           = FieldName | Expression | LiteralValue .
> FieldName     = identifier .
> Element       = Expression | LiteralValue .
> ```

As you can see, `KeyedElement` may contain an optional `Key ":"` part.

> ... **The key is interpreted as** a field name for struct literals, **an index for array and slice literals**, and a key for map literals.

Note that you can mix keyed and "unkeyed" elements, and they don't have to be contiguous. Also, if a key is missing in a slice literal, the index will be the previous index + 1.

```
type Step struct{}

var steps = []*Step{
    0:       &Step{},
    1:       &Step{},
    &Step{}, // implicit index: 2
    5:       &Step{},
}
fmt.Println(steps)
```

Output of the above (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/0nM6DYmnsC1)):

```
[0x559008 0x559008 0x559008 <nil> <nil> 0x559008]
```

They keys may also be "out of order", meaning this is also valid:

```
var steps = []*Step{
    5:       &Step{},
    0:       &Step{},
    1:       &Step{},
    &Step{}, // implicit index: 2
}
```

This outputs the same. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/JykLlwfbrIH).